# C# syntax and DbConnection

Tags: c#

This must be a very simple question for someone who knows C#, but I am a bit lost.

Class `DbConnection` derives from `IDbConnection`; classes `OleDbConnection` and `OdbcConnection`. I need `objConnection` be either `OleDbConnection` or`OdbcConnection`.

```
string connStr = CONNECTION_STRING.Replace("<FILENAME>", fullFileName);
IDbConnection objConnection = (myswitch) ? (IDbConnection)new OdbcConnection(connStr) 
                                         : (IDbConnection)new OleDbConnection(connStr);
objConnection.Open();
objConnection.GetSchema(...);
objConnection.Close();
```

Class `DbConnection` cannot be instantiated but has a method `GetSchema` I would like to call (I also call `open` and `close`). IDbConnection  does not have these methodsCast to `DbConnection` does not work. Is there a way to implement these calls without a big `if` and repetition of the code?

**EDIT: I am using these connections to read Excel files, apparently I need OdbcConnection for 64bit machines (not sure, still investigating)**

Comment: is there any exception when casting to DbConnection?

Comment: Maybe just declare objConnection as a DbConnection instead of IDbConnection

Comment: Also, objConnection.Open() should be wrapped with a using() so that it gets disposed in the event of an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
IDbConnection objConnection = (myswitch) ? (IDbConnection)new OdbcConnection(connStr) 
                                     : (IDbConnection)new OleDbConnection(connStr);
```

With:

```
// no need to cast here.
DbConnection objConnection = (myswitch) ? new OdbcConnection(connStr) 
                                     : new OleDbConnection(connStr);
```

Since `DbConnection` implements `IDbConnection`, there is no problem using the class instead of the interface.

In fact, it should be the preferred way to go in this specific case, since the class has what you need but the interface doesn't. This way, your `objConnection` variable will be able to use `Dbconnection`'s methods and properties without any compiler errors.

Comment: Thanks! Had a problem because out in-house DbConnection class was used by default instead of the standard C# one. Cast to DbConnection was needed though, because both expressions on the RHS need to be of the same type, and in this particular case, C# cannot deduce that this type needs to be DbConnection.

Answer (score -2):

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    insertCommand.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    affectedRows = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Can't you use this approach??

Comment: Hardly a solution, seeing as the OP isn't going for the SQL related classes. Her problem seems more related to object building issues and less related to this.

Comment: If you want to read excel file then try this:

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/71788-reading-excel-files-in-c/

Comment: Interop opens an instance of Excel (you can see it in taskmgr); this is not convenient for me.